# keep same column when navigating by pages?

Tags: scrolling

`<c-d>` and `<c-u>` both, by default, drop you in the first non-whitespace column of the given row.

This behavior is kind of distracting when quickly scanning through pages. Is there a way to get way to configure vim to keep the cursor in the same column when scrolling by pages. I have `virtualedit` enabled, so not-moving the cursor is always possible, even if `<c-u>`/`<c-d>` moves focus to an empty line.

Comment: I don't think you can do this

Answer (score 9):

In addition to setting `virtualedit=all`,

```
:set nostartofline
```

Answer (score 5):

The relevant option is `startofline`.

`set nostartofline` will prevent vim from moving to just after leading indentation after performing a motion like `c-u`, `c-d`, `gg`, `G`.

I can confirm that it interacts in the expected way (not moving the column) when `virtualedit` is enabled.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.